# Storing values into report variable in SSRS reporting

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008-r2

I am making a report in asp.net and for that i want to store data from datatable into a report variable, but the problem is that i want the third row 2nd columns data into variable and i do not know how to do it please provide me any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataRow` has also an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z.aspx):

```
Object cellValue = dt.Rows[3][2];
```

But i would prefer the strongly typed `Field` extension method which also supports [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) types:

```
int number = dt.Rows[3].Field<int>(2);
```

or even more readable and less error-prone with the name of the column:

```
double otherNumber = dt.Rows[3].Field<double>("SecondColumnName");
```